# PHP form resubmitting

Tags: php, forms

I have a small project I have been working on. I had to create a area conversion calculator using one file or PHP_SELF. The problem I am having is the form is working and outputs the number, but it will only ouput the last if statement no matter what conversion method I pick. It will always output Sq.Miles.

```
if (!empty($_POST['con'])) {
    $con = $_POST['con'];
} else {
    $error .= "You need to select a conversion Method. <br>";
}
if (!empty($_POST['number'])) {
    $num = $_POST['number'];
    } else {
    $error .= "You need to type in a number. <br>";
} 
if (empty($error)) {
    if ($con = "SFSM") {
        $result = $num * 0.093 . " Sq. Meters";
    }
    if ($con = "SYSM") {
        $result = $num * 0.84 . " Sq. Meters";
    }
    if ($con = "SMSK") {
        $result = $num * 2.6 . " Sq. Kiometers";
    }
    if ($con = "SMSF") {
        $result = $num * 10.76 . " Sq. Feet";
    }
    if ($con = "SMSY") {
        $result = $num * 1.2 . " Sq. Yards";
    }
    if ($con = "SKSM") {
        $result = $num * 0.38 . " Sq. Miles";
    }
}
}
?>
<form method="post" action="area2.php">
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Area Conversions</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Conversion Method</td>
<td>Number</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="con">
 <option selected="selected" style="color:#CCC"></option>
 <option value="SFSM">Square Feet to Square Meters</option>
 <option value="SYSM">Square Yards to Square Meters</option>
 <option value="SMSK">Square Miles to Square Kilometers</option>
 <option value="SMSF">Square Meters to Square Feet</option>
 <option value="SMSY">Square Meters to Square Yards</option>
 <option value="SKSM">Square Kilometers to Square Miles</option>
 </select>
 </td>
 <td>
  <input type="text" name="number" size="10" value = "<?php if ($num){ echo $num; } else           {           echo "Insert Number"; } ?>" onfocus="this.value==this.defaultValue?this.value='':null"/><br />
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="2">
       <input type="submit" value="Calculate" name="submit" />
       <input type="reset" value="reset" name="reset" />
</td>
</tr>
<?php
if (!empty($error)) {
echo $error;
}elseif (!empty($result)) {
echo "<tr><td colspan=\"2\">Result: " . $result . " </td></tr>";
}
?>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: tip : change `if` to `switch`

Comment: Like @diEcho said, please use a switch here. It'll make your code more manageable, and is created to handle this sort of thing.

Comment: would I change all if statements to switch or just cetain ones?

Comment: If I wanted to add more conversion methods as in a drop down box of Area Conversions Mass Conversions Etc. Could I use the switch method to call different codes, as in if Conversion method is selected use this code and so on? This is the first time I've come across switch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
if ($con == "SFSM") {
```

The `=` operator is assignment; `==` is comparison.

Essentially, your if statements are all evaluating to true; and since they all set the variable, it's only the last call that's actually appearing

Comment: Certainly explains why it always gets the last one.  Winner Winner!

Comment: I can't count the number of times I've done this myself. It's one of the hazards of switching between programming languages whose syntax is almost identical.

Comment: Thank you so much I overlooked the whole = and ==. This worked!